# Same e-mail user, different address?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, outlook

I was wondering why using `foo.bar@gmail.com` works but not `foo.bar@outlook.com`.

In Gmail, `foo.bar@gmail.com` and `foobar@gmail.com` (and any combination of periods in the username) is equivalent.

Is this a hidden feature in Gmail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could say this is kind of a *hidden* trick of Gmail. Here is what Google says about it:

> Gmail doesn’t recognize dots as characters within usernames, you can
>   add or remove the dots from a Gmail address without changing the
>   actual destination address; they’ll all go to your inbox, and only
>   yours

And the [makeuseof](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/1-awesome-gmail-tip-you-dont-know-about-seriously/) article about it.

Microsoft didn't choose to provide this for outlook, probably because they migrated the hotmail accounts where the `.` (dot) could be used a character in the username.

Note that you also have two similar tricks:

- the [mymail+anything@gmail.com](http://mywebexperience.com/tricks/gmail-single-email-multiple-alias-feature-using-plus/)
- the [mymail@googlemail.com](http://mywebexperience.com/tricks/gmail-is-equal-to-googlemail/) is equal to mymail@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you for providing a solid response to my question. I was unsure as to why it was doing this, but your explanation on Microsoft's Hotmail migration would explain it.

Answer (score 1):

There is lifehacker article called [Reformat your Gmail address with dots](http://lifehacker.com/269619/reformat-your-gmail-address-with-dots) that discusses this great feature.